# Continuous or categorical data. Modeling depth, that is continuous through a range of values, but has a max depth that is discrete

Tags: dataset, continuous-data, categorical-encoding, censoring

I'm modeling depth to bedrock.  These data are continuous through a range of depths, but have a max value that equates to as far as we could dig with our soil auger. So they are continuous through a range, but there is a max value that is discrete that appears on multiple samples. I have been doing exploratory data analysis with multiple regression and Random Forest. Should I being treating theses data as classes, or categories?

Comment: You data are [censored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)) at the maximum depth you could dig to. Many questions on site discuss issues related to [censoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censoring). When you record the maximum value you're not recording the depth at which you struck bedrock, you're recording a value you know must be less than the depth at which it occurs. You'll get biased results in regression-type models unless you take proper account of the effect of censoring.

Comment: Ok, great.  This gives me a start to find a solution.  If I may be lazy, how is bias introduced?

Comment: A simple example. Let's take our response to be temperature of something using a digital thermometer but which cannot record temperature above 100C; it just maxes out at "100". We want estimate the average temperature under a particular set of conditions where there's a fair bit of variation in temp. We get 91.43, 100, 98.58, 100. Whatever the 100 values should have been (let's say 103.47, 106.28 for concreteness), 100 is smaller than them so the average with the 100 values in there is too small. (On the other hand, if you remove those and average the rest, it's even smaller!)

Comment: If we have a distributional model we can still write down a likelihood (for both censored and uncensored data) and maximize it, and that way get a more reasonable estimate of the quantity we were after. (I expect you'll probably end up with a more specific question relating to your particular problem)